# Easy mysql question regarding primary keys and an insert

Tags: mysql, insert, primary-key

In mysql, how do I get the primary key used for an insert operation, when it is autoincrementing.

Basically, i want the new autoincremented value to be returned when the statement completes.

Thanks!

Comment: Clarification:
Code has insert then a last_insert_id. Two of these statements execute almost at the same time and the exec order turns into

insert #1
insert #2
last_insert_id #1 completes and returns the id from insert#2
last_insert_id #2 completes and returns the id from insert#2

Can this happen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your clarification comment says that you're interested in making sure that LAST_INSERT_ID() doesn't give the wrong result if another concurrent INSERT happens.  Rest assured that it is safe to use LAST_INSERT_ID() regardless of other concurrent activity.  LAST_INSERT_ID() returns only the most recent ID generated during the current session.

You can try it yourself:

1. Open two shell windows, run mysql
   client in each and connect to
   database.
2. Shell 1: INSERT into a table with an
   AUTO_INCREMENT key.
3. Shell 1: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(),
   see result.
4. Shell 2: INSERT into the same table.
5. Shell 2: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(),
   see result different from shell 1.
6. Shell 1: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
   again, see a repeat of earlier
   result.

If you think about it, this is the only way that makes sense.  All databases that support auto-incrementing key mechanisms must act this way.  If the result depends on a race condition with other clients possibly INSERTing concurrently, then there would be no dependable way to get the last inserted ID value in your current session.

Comment: @Bill Karwin  thx a lot for this helpful post. A question: Say in a multi threaded environment the last Auto inc key value available was 10.. then the thread of shell 1 fails to insert and at the same moment shell two is inserting.. what would be the last_insert_id() ? 11 or 12? thx a lot

Comment: @shadesco: Depends on your version of MySQL, but in 5.1 and later with InnoDB, the first session would increment the auto-inc and that value would be lost.  Then the second session would get 12.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Answer (score 6):

MySQL's **[LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)**

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL Docs describe the function: [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Answer (score -1):

[select max(primary_key_column_name) from table_name]
Ahhh not nessecarily. I am not an MySQL guy but there are specific way to get the last inserted id for the last completed action that are a little more robust than this. What if an insert has happened between you writing to the table and querying it? I know about because it stung me many moons ago (so yeah it does happen).
If all else fails read the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html