# Primary key from inserted row jdbc?

Tags: java, jdbc, identity

Is there a cross database platform way to get the primary key of the record you have just inserted?

I noted that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165156/easy-mysql-question-regarding-primary-keys-and-an-insert) says that you can get it by Calling `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` and I think that you can call `SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'Identity';` is there a common way to do this accross databases in jdbc?

If not how would you suggest I implement this for a piece of code that could access any of SQL Server, MySQL and Oracle?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Copied from my code:

```
pInsertOid = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_OID_SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

where pInsertOid is a prepared statement.

you can then obtain the key:

```
// fill in the prepared statement and
pInsertOid.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = pInsertOid.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) {
  int newId = rs.getInt(1);
  oid.setId(newId);
}
```

Hope this gives you a good starting point.

Comment: Works with Postgres, but not with Oracle

Comment: On Sybase ASE this just works if you have installed the metadata accessor information tables. Otherwise you have to use `@@identity`.

Answer (score 27):

extraneon's answer, although correct, **doesn't work for Oracle**.

The way you do this for Oracle is:

```
String key[] = {"ID"}; //put the name of the primary key column

ps = con.prepareStatement(insertQuery, key);
ps.executeUpdate();

rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) {
    generatedKey = rs.getLong(1);
}
```

Comment: Worked for me with Oracle 11g Express and Java 8.

Comment: Worked! One should give special attention to `rs.getLong(1)` you have to provide the index and not the name

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the [Statement.executeUpdate()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) and [Statement.getGeneratedKeys()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()) methods? There is a [developerWorks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jdbcnew/) that mentions the approach.

Also, in JDBC 4.0 Sun added the [row_id feature](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/08/02/jjdbc-4-enhancements-in-java-se-6.html) that allows you to get a unique handle on a row. The feature is supported by Oracle and DB2. For sql server you will probably need a third party driver such as [this one](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/jdbc/mssql/merlia/).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

for oracle, Hibernate uses NEXT_VALUE from a sequence if you have mapped a sequence for PKEY value generation.

Not sure what it does for MySQL or MS SQL server

Answer (score 1):

Spring provides some useful support for [this operation](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-auto-genereted-keys) and the reference guide seems to answer your question:

> There is not a standard single way to
>   create an appropriate
>   PreparedStatement (which explains why
>   the method signature is the way it
>   is). An example that works on Oracle
>   and may not work on other platforms
>   is...

I've tested this example on MySQL and it works there too, but I can't speak for other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

For databases that conform to SQL-99, you can use identity columns:
CREATE TABLE sometable (id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 101) PRIMARY KEY, ...

Use [getGeneratedKeys()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) to retrieve the key that was just inserted with [executeUpdate(String sql, int autoGeneratedKeys)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). Use Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS for 2nd parameter to executeUpdate()

Answer (score -2):

Just declare id column as id integer not NULL primary key `auto_increment`

after this execute this code

```
ResultSet ds=st.executeQuery("select * from user");
                while(ds.next())
                {

                 ds.last();
                System.out.println("please note down your registration id  which is "+ds.getInt("id"));
                }
                ds.close();
```

the above code will show you the current row's id

if you remove `ds.last()` than it will show all values of id column