# Solution Compatible Oracle and MySQL for LIMIT clause

Tags: mysql, oracle, limit, compatibility, clause

Is there a solution that is compatible Oracle and MySql to limit the number of rows returned by a query ?

For example in mysql there is the LIMT clause

`SELECT * FROM myTable LIMT 10;`

In Oracle we use a condition on the rownum column

I want some code that works for both MySQL and Oracle

Answer (score 1):

If your table has a unique id column (or combination of columns), you can do the following:

```
select t.*
from t
where (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.id <= t.id) <= 10;
```

The correlated subquery in the `where` clause is standard SQL syntax so it should run in any database.

The performance should be ok on small tables.  It would be improved with an index on `t(id)`.

Answer (score 0):

in oracle it's

```
select * from mytable where rownum < 11
```

the alternative is an analytic function but mysql does not support that.

Comment: I believe @abderrahim_05 want a SQL that works with both of them without any modification.

Comment: Well, I'm working on application that must work for both Oracle and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is perfect auto-increasement (no number is skipped) field and no other condition

To get the last 5 records

```
SELECT * FROM account
HAVING (SELECT MAX(id) FROM account) - 5 < id
```

To get the first 5 records

```
SELECT * FROM account
HAVING (SELECT MIN(id) FROM account) + 5 > id
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a solution without a database abstraction layer, especially if this solution is to perform.

Even if you found a solution for this specific problem, there would be another 99 problems down the road to database portability. I have posted my experience in the answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16716543/2390083)

The good news for this specific problem is that for DB2, PostgreSql, Oracle and MySql you can simply wrap/extend a query to become a query with a limit. But you need handle this somewhere in your application.