# Unable to execute prepared Statement from DAO

Tags: java, sqlite

So currently Im trying to do get the auto-incremented primary key by following this answer
[Primary key from inserted row jdbc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201887/primary-key-from-inserted-row-jdbc) but apparently the program can't even reach that line and the error appeared on the `ps.executeQuery()` line after debugging the program, the error it display was only `"executeQuery" is not a known variable in the current context.` that line, which didn't make sense to me. So how do I go pass this hurdle?

```java
public static int createNewLoginUsers(String newPassword, String newRole) throws SQLException{
        Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        int id = 0;

        try{
            String sql = "INSERT into Login(password, role) VALUES(?,?)";           
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, newPassword);
            ps.setString(2, newRole);
            ps.executeUpdate();

            st = conn.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from Login");

            rs.last();
            System.out.println(rs.getInt("username"));
            id = rs.getInt("username");

            rs.close();


        } finally{
            try{
            conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        }
        return id;

    }
```

The part of the method which calls the createNewLoginUsers method

```java
if(newPasstxtfld.getText().equals(retypeNewPasstxtfld.getText())){
                    //update into database
                    try {
                    int username = CreateUsersDAO.createNewLoginUsers( (String) newUserRoleBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(), newPasstxtfld.getText());
                    Alert confirmation = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                    confirmation.setHeaderText("New User Details has been created. Your username is " + username);
                    confirmation.showAndWait();
                } catch (SQLException e) {

                }
```

EDIT:
Databases table added and it's in the provided link below
https://imgur.com/a/Dggp2kc and edit to the codes instead of 2 try blocks in one method i have placed it into a different similar method, updated my codes to the current one I have.

Comment: The first query is an INSERT - try `ps.executeUpdate()`.

Comment: I tried `ps.executeUpdate()` too, it didnt work quite well for me. @AndrewS